# Foreign Key equivalent for ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two simple ArrayLists, one for 3 Buses and one for 3 Routes.

```
ArrayList<Bus> busList = new ArrayList<Bus>();
busList.add(new Bus("B101", 20, 4, 16));
busList.add(new Bus("B102", 20, 6, 14));
busList.add(new Bus("B103", 20, 0, 20));

ArrayList<Route> routeList = new ArrayList<Route>();
routeList.add(new Route("R75", "Atlanta", "Cincinnati", "Chattanooga, Knoxville, Lexington", 150));
routeList.add(new Route("R95", "Miami", "Savannah", "Jacksonville", 200));
routeList.add(new Route("R275", "Milford", "Mariemont", "Loveland, Blue Ash", 25));
```

I want each bus to be associated to one route. My experience with DB technologies, leads me to think I want some kind of foreign key setup? Something like Bus B101 would have R95 in its ArrayList to associate to a specific route.

The functionality I desire is taking user input to search the route ArrayList for a specific start and end location, then determine the seat availability of the specific linked Bus.

Comment: This is not something you're going to find in Java.

Comment: If a Bus `has a` Route , may you want change Bus class and add Route property for example `private Route route`

Comment: If you think of a foreign key as a pointer to a record and both records are represented by objects in `Java`, then you could consider a `Route` field in `Bus` as that pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For associations use a HashMap.

```
Map<String,Route> busToRoutesMap = new HashMap<String,Route>();
// key = "B101", value = R95; getName() delivers String "B101"
busToRoutesMap.put(busList.get(0).getName(), routeList.get(1));
```

to retrieve the associations:

```
Route route = busToRoutesMap.get(busList.get(0).getName());
```

this will deliver Route R95.

I personally prefer primitive keys, such that I can serialize it better to a file.
And some other advantages (faster, no need to override hashcode())

In that case I would not use the BUS object as key, but a busID, or in your case the busName.

Comment: +1 for good answer but I always use generics first so `Map<Bus,Route> busToRoutesMap = new HashMap<Bus,Route>();`

Comment: I always, too. I have fixed It while you have written your comment.

Comment: also have to override equals and hashCode method

Comment: @nachokk  i added a paragraph at the end.

Comment: @AlexWien, this seems like it could work for me as well, however I am getting a compile error that the method add() is undefined. I don't have a busName so I changed .getName() to .getBusId(). This doesn't cause the error if I can tell correctly..

Comment: @AlexWien, actually changing from getName to getBusId does throw the error. However, I don't use a getName() getter..

Comment: @user2547757 i fixed: on maps it is called put(), not add(). if you use a busId of typoe Integer then you have to replace the <String, with <Integer,

Comment: @AlexWien, thank you for the correction. I was reading about put() right before I saw you update. If I'm reading the code correctly (I'm totally new to mapping), this is associating index 0 busID of bus (so B101) to index 1 routeId of route (so R95)? Is this making a "bridge" from an index of bus to an index of route or just inserting the routeId into a table with the bus element?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `Route` property (or `ArrayList<Route>`) in each `Bus` that stores a reference to the same `Route` instance.

Answer (score 0):

An array list uses an integer->element relationship. You want a map. Since any type of element can be a key, values can refer to keys. Note that keys must be unique.

I'd recommend using a hashmap or treemap for both tables. Tree maps work by comparison, and hash maps work by hashing.

If you ever need multiple values for one key, make the map use an ArrayList of [value class] as the actual value type.

Since objects use references they can refer to each other and allow for changes in each that will propagate to the other maps.